# How does svelte handle reactivity inside imports

Tags: javascript, svelte

I have an object that is altered by imported functions.

https://svelte.dev/repl/e934087af1dc4a25a1ee52cf3fd3bbea?version=3.12.1

I want to know how I can make my changes be reflected in my test variable

```
// app.svelte
<script>
import {testFunction} from "./Simulations.js";

let a = [{"b":1}, {"b":2}];
$:test = a;

setTimeout(() => {
    // this function changes the value of a
    // while not reflecting the changes in test
    testFunction(a);
    // the code commented below works
    //a[0].b = 55;
    console.log("Value changed asdasda") 
},1000);

</script>

{#each test as t}
    This is a test value: {t.b} <br/>
{/each}


// simulation.js
function testFunction(variable){
// this code changes the value of the object dutifully
// it seems however that the change is not picked up
// by the reactive variable
    variable[0].b = 55;
}

export {testFunction}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the [Svelte Tutorial](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/updating-arrays-and-objects) (a good read, by the way), Svelte only reacts on assignments in the current component. When mutating the variable in some other file, Svelte is not able to pick that up.

One possible solution is to return the mutated array from `testFunction` and assign it:

```
// app.svelte
setTimeout(() => {
    a = testFunction(a);
},1000);

// simulation.js
function testFunction(variable){
    variable[0].b = 55;
    return variable;
}
```

If you do this, you don't need the `test` variable at all:

```
<script>
    import {testFunction} from "./Simulations.js";

    let a = [{"b":1}, {"b":2}];

    setTimeout(() => {
        a = testFunction(a);
    },1000);
</script>

{#each a as val}
    This is a test value: {val.b} <br/>
{/each}
```

---

**Edit**: I should also mention that the simplest fix (and maybe an easier one if `testFunction` is from an external source) is to just reassign `a` after the call to `testFunction`:

```
setTimeout(() => {
    testFunction(a);
    a = a
},1000);
```

This works, but it feels a bit inelegant.